# Placing a div by the bottom right corner of another

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I currently have two `div`s that are within another `div`, one is a `table` with a list of items that is updated by using a `textbox` that is positioned next to it, I am trying to position the `textbox` in the bottom right corner, I have tried floating/positioning and it doesn't seem to have any real effect on it, the first image is how it currently is, the second image is how I would like it to be.
[image: Current position:]

[image: desired effect]

**ASP.NET code:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="PrimaryContentPlaceHolder" runat="Server">
<%--<div style="margin-bottom: 20px; width: 300px;">--%>
    <table class="Grid" style="width:300px;float:left; margin-right:10px;" >
        <tr>
            <th>
                Banned Domains
            </th>
            <td runat="server" id="bannedDomains">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   <%-- </div>--%>
<div style="position:relative; bottom:0px;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="bannedDomainText" runat="server" Rows="5" TextMode="SingleLine"
        Width="150px" Height="19px" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" style="padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;" PostBackUrl="~/admin/bespoke/Green-FreeShipping.aspx"
        Text="Add to List" />
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

**css:**

```
    #Content table
{
border-collapse: collapse;
}

#Content table.Grid 
{
width: 100%;
clear: both;
margin: 12px 0 12px 0;
}

#Content table.Grid th, #Content table.Grid td
{
background-color: White;
border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
}

#Content table.Grid th
{
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

#Content table tr:hover td
{
background: #f9f9f9;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Apologies, I posted before I had finished the post!

Comment: Your code barely corresponds with what you are trying to achieve... Do you have any more code?

Comment: Isn't the image clear enough? :P I've posted a picture of exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, posted that before you posted the CSS!

Comment: Was going to say :P pretty sure the person who down voted did as well :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, use it like this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hcWG3/)

CSS

```
.Grid {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    height: 400px;
    width:300px;
    position: relative;
}

div.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

textarea {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<table class="Grid">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Banned Domains
        </th>
       <td runat="server" id="bannedDomains"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried your method and it doesn't seem to handle it properly :( I get this result: http://puu.sh/1mKdm

Comment: @HelloWorld what doesn't handle properly?

Answer (score 1):

here's one way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/5DjM9/

```
<div class="div1">LEFT</div>
<div class="div2"><div>RIGHT</div></div>


.div1 {
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:#ccc;
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
}

.div2 {
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:#ccc;
float:left;
position:relative;
}
.div2 div {
width:200px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
background:red;
}
```

Comment: This actually pushes the box/button above the div :)

Comment: If you look at my fiddle (linked in my answer) you'll see that the principle is sound and it works. You just need to apply the basics of what I've shown you to your specific example.

Comment: Yeah :) I know thanks! I feel like I have something else on my page that is conflicting with it because all of the simple ideas that I have tried seem to have the opposite effect to what they should..

Answer (score 0):

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/nobuts/WzUjr/

```
<div class="big_box">
    <div class="cols"><div id="table">div/table</div></div>
        <div class="cols"><div id="textbox">div/textbox</div></div>
    <br style="clear:both">
</div>

.big_box{
    background:red;
    color:#000;
    height:250px;
    padding:5px;
}

.cols{
    height:240px;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    position:relative;
}
#table{
    background:#ff9900;
    height:100%;
    width:250px;
}
#textbox{
    background:#ff9900;
    bottom:0px;
    height:30px;
    top:auto;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the float:left on the `<table>` element is "stuck" the solution is:

1. add a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` right after the `<table>` ( it can be empty ).
2. remove float from table and play with position.

hope it helped :-)